# Access ng-model from one div to another div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to access `ng-model` value from one div to another div.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="key in condition.keys">
    <select class="form-control" ng-show="key.aggregator" ng-model="key.aggregator" ng-options="field.name as field.label for (name, field) in aggregators"></select>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="key.field" ng-options="s.field as s.field for s in subSchema($parent.condition,$index)" ng-change="onFieldChange($parent.condition,$index)" required>
        <option value="">choose one</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-left">{{key.field}}
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="condition.operator" ng-options="field.name as field.label for (name, field) in fields | instanceFilter :key.field :condition" required>
        <option value="">choose operator</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a `key.field` in `ng-model` in one div. I want to access this `ng-model` value on another div where you can see **instanceFilter**. Is it possible? Thanks in adavnce please solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use the same `ng-model` binding in as many `div`s as you like which sit under the same scope.

It's not obvious what your code is trying to accomplish, but the `"key.field"` which you are binding to within your `ng-repeat` div is not in the same scope as the rest of the page outside the `ng-repeat`.

You should assign both the `ng-model="key.field"` to a different variable which is on the outer scope and not part of the `key` which only has scope for that individual item in your collection.

Comment: Is it not possible to use $parent.key.field for that div

Comment: @user3722785 think about loop variables in other programming languages. which key do you want to access?

Answer (score 0):

Go to that controller,
then assign 
**$rootScope.key.field=" ";**
 **

> **The rootScope is available in the entire application.**

**